# JGit clone repository

Tags: repository, clone, jgit

I'm trying to clone Git repository with JGit and I have problem with UnsupportedCredentialItem.

My code:

```
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(PATH).readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();

Git git = new Git(repository);              
CloneCommand clone = git.cloneRepository();
clone.setBare(false);
clone.setCloneAllBranches(true);
clone.setDirectory(PATH).setURI(url);
UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider user = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(login, password);                
clone.setCredentialsProvider(user);
clone.call();
```

It will occur Exception:

```
 org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://git@github.com:22: Passphrase for C:\Users\Marek\.ssh\id_rsa at
 org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.get(UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.java:110)....
```

But if I delete file known_hosts in .ssh\ It will occur different Exception

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.UnsupportedCredentialItem: ssh://git@github.com:22: The authenticity of host 'github.com' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting?
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.get(UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider.java:110)....
```

Is there any possibility to type "yes" to that question or just skip it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I think if you login with username and password, you need https. For ssh you will need a public key that matches the one on record with github.

Answer (score 4):

This will do it (like @michals, only less code) if using username / password with ssh

```
public void gitClone() throws GitAPIException {
    final File localPath = new File("./TestRepo");
    Git.cloneRepository()
        .setURI(REMOTE_URL)
        .setDirectory(localPath)
        .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("***", "***"))
        .call();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you would want to check the github help:

http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

Especially the part about generating ssh keys (`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"`). Read the article for your environment, and you'll understand how to get a better configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The reason was passphrase set for rsa private key. When I remove passphrase for this key it started work without any `CredentialsProvider`.

`UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider` probably don't support passphrase. If you would like to have passphrase set, you could define you own CredentialProvider, which will support it, for example:

```
CloneCommand clone = Git.cloneRepository()
    .setURI("...")
    .setCredentialsProvider(new CredentialsProvider() {

        @Override
        public boolean supports(CredentialItem... items) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isInteractive() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean get(URIish uri, CredentialItem... items)
                throws UnsupportedCredentialItem {

            for (CredentialItem item : items) {
                    if (item instanceof CredentialItem.StringType) {
                        ((CredentialItem.StringType) item).
                            setValue(new String("YOUR_PASSPHRASE"));
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

clone.call();
```

It works for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, though my setup was a bit different. Leaving this here in case anyone else encounters something similar. I had overridden my configure method and createDefaultJSch method according to this tutorial: https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/

I had something like:

```
@Override
public void configure( Transport transport ) {
  SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
  sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
}

@Override
protected JSch createDefaultJSch( FS fs ) throws JSchException {
  JSch defaultJSch = super.createDefaultJSch( fs );
  defaultJSch.addIdentity( "/path/to/private_key" );
  return defaultJSch;
}
```

I ended up changing my createdDefaultJSch method to getSch (adding the appropriate parameters) and adding removeAllIdentity():

```
@Override
public JSch getJSch(final OpenSshConfig.Host hc, FS fs) throws JSchException {
  JSch jSch = super.getJSch(hc, fs)
  jSch.removeAllIdentity()
  jSch.addIdentity( "/path/to/private_key" )
  return jSch
}
```

No idea why this worked, but I found the getSch thing from this answer (coincidentally by the same guy who wrote the tutorial): [Using Keys with JGit to Access a Git Repository Securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686643/using-keys-with-jgit-to-access-a-git-repository-securely)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me whether you want to do username/password authentication or public/private key authentication. Either way, `CredentialsProvider` will not be used, according to this. You need to configure the transport. First, create a transport configuration callback:

```
SshSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new JschConfigSessionFactory() {
  @Override
  protected void configure( Host host, Session session ) {
    // If you are using username/password authentication, add the following line
    session.setPassword( "password" );
  }
} );

TransportConfigCallback transportConfigCallback = new TransportConfigCallback() {
  @Override
  public void configure( Transport transport ) {
    SshTransport sshTransport = ( SshTransport )transport;
    sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory( sshSessionFactory );
  }
};
```

Then configure the command with it:

```
clone.setTransportConfigCallback( transportConfigCallback );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the repository is private and needs authentication, you(@Scruger) will do it using **username**/**password** with ssh for clone repository.

```
private UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider configAuthentication(String user, String password) {
            return new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(user, password ); 
        }

    public void clonneRepositoryWithAuthentication(String link, String directory,String branch,String user, String password){
         System.out.println("cloning repository private from bitcketebuk");
        try {
            Git.cloneRepository()//function responsible to clone repository
                                       .setURI(link)// set link to repository git
                                       .setDirectory(new File(Constants.PATH_DEFAULT + directory))//Defined the path local the cloning
                                       .setCredentialsProvider(configAuthentication(user, password))
                                       .setCloneAllBranches(true)//Defined clone all branch exists on repository
                                       .call();//execute call the clone repository git
            System.out.println("Cloning sucess.....");
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            System.err.println("Error Cloning repository " + link + " : "+ e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```