Git repository gets large due to version control of a large file
I have a JSON file in a git repository, which takes up a lot of space(1.3MB), since apparently, git stores the whole content for each version of that file, according to what is said here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397209/how-does-git-manage-its-file-version#:~:text=Git%2C%20at%20least%20conceptually%2C%20stores%20the%20entire%20content%20of%20each%20version%20of%20every%20file%20in%20the%20repository
I am wondering if there is something I can do to minimize the space, and still be able to view the revision history as usual, for that file? It should be said that I cannot remove any content in that file.

If it doesn't change too often, the size increase should be rather limited. There's git lfs for large files, but 1,3M doesn't really qualify, I guess.

The problem is that it does change quite often, several times a week.

Also keep in mind that git compresses data before storing it as objects, so each blob made from this file (each new recorded state of it) won't increase the repo by 1,3M, only a fraction of that. To me what you describe still sounds quite manageable.

Agree with @RomainValeri, but why do you keep a big JSON file like this. What is the type of this JSON? If it is relate to the code, I think it can be shrinked or it's a big issue in code. If it's a generative file, add it to .gitignore.

@AnthonyNguyen It depends on the context, though. Some JSON files, even generated ones, can make sense in a code repository. An example that comes to mind is a "composer.json" describing dependencies.

git will eventually get around to packing things up for storage efficiency on its own, try git repack -ad for a quick check, you can get very, very aggressive with the options on that.  If that file is in a directory with a boatload of other files, like many hundreds or  even thousands, you'll want a bigger --window.  Git's defaults trade off compression cost with the value of the savings in common use.
