# Git and binary data, best storage method

Tags: git, binary-diff

Im in the unfortunate situation of having to store some binary files in git,

However I can choose how the data is stored on disk - in Git (in our own format which only the build system needs to read).

I'd like to avoid talking specifics too much, since I dont think its so important - but to give some context these are many icon files, but the same question would apply to many small sound-files or 3d-models too.

converting these files into one large image will be a build step, so the images can be stored however we like in git.

- Binary compressed (eg, PNG (image), FLAC (sound))
- Binary uncompressed (eg, PPM (image), Uncompressed-WAV (sound))
- ASCII representation of binary data (eg, mime encoding, XPM (image))

Lets assume there will be changes to some files occasionally - so avoiding storing a new binary blob for every small change to a pixel - would be nice.

I'm interested to know:

- Which options will store a totally new binary blob each time the binary file changes (even a few bytes).
- Does git diff uncompressed binary data better then compressed data (which may change a lot even with minor edits to the uncompressed data).
- I would assume storing many small binary files is less overhead long term, compared to one large binary file, assuming only some of the files are periodically modified, can git handle small changes to large binary files efficiently?

All things considered what are the best options for avoiding a large git repo (as edits are made to the binary files) assuming using binary files can't be avoided completely?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the following SO question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git

Comment: This includes some useful info but focuses on the case where its impractical to store binary files in git, In our case we have about 1mb of icons, and mostly they never change so this is something git can likely manage without so much trouble. However, 1mb for every edit is not acceptable either, which is why Im looking into options for splitting the files.

Comment: Look at Taders comments in one of the answers where he talks about git gc and diff/compression of binary files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which options will store a totally new binary blob each time the binary file changes (even a few bytes).

All of them.  All blobs (indeed, all objects in the repo) are stored "intact" (more or less) whenever they are "loose objects".  The only thing done with them is to give them a header and compress them with deflate compression.

At the same time, though, loose objects are eventually combined into "packs".  Git does delta-compression on files in packs: see [Is the git binary diff algorithm (delta storage) standardized?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9478023/1256452).  Based on the answers there, you'd be much better off not "pre-compressing" the binaries, so that the pack-file delta algorithm can find long strings of matching binary data.

> Does git diff uncompressed binary data better then compressed data (which may change a lot even with minor edits to the uncompressed data).

I have not tried it but the overall implication is that the answer to this should be "yes".

> I would assume storing many small binary files is less overhead long term, compared to one large binary file, assuming only some of the files are periodically modified, can git handle small changes to large binary files efficiently?

Certainly all files that are completely unchanged will be stored with a lot of "de-duplication" instantly, as their SHA-1 checksums will be identical across all commits, so that each tree names the very same blob in the repository.  If `foo.icon` is the same across thousands of commits, there's just the one blob (whatever the SHA-1 for `foo.icon` turns out to be) stored.

---

I'd recommend experimenting a bit: create some dummy test repos with proposed binaries, make proposed changes, and see how big the repos are before and after running `git gc` to re-pack the loose objects.  Note that there are a lot of tuneables; in particular, you might want to fuss with `window`, `depth` and `window-memory` settings (which can be set on command lines or in git config entries).