# What does "*.jpg binary -delta" do in the .gitattributes file?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, gitattributes

[This thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/146957/focus=147598) is suggesting placing

```
*.jpg binary -delta
```

in the `.gitattribute` file for repos in git but I am not sure what it does. I cannot find any examples of the '-delta' flag for git.

The purpose is to apparently speed up commit or push times for larger files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That could be related to:

#### Packing objects

```
delta
```

> Delta compression will not be attempted for blobs for paths with the attribute delta set to false.

I detail delta storage in "[Is the git binary diff algorithm (delta storage) standardized?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/6309)".

That isn't set by default of binary files because:

> our originally intended target audience are people who use git as a source code control system.

[Jeff King adds](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/146957/focus=147598):

> I delta jpgs in one of my repositories. It is useful if the exif metadata changes but the image data does not. I assume you could do the same with other formats which have compressed and uncompressed portions (I also do it with video containers).  I don't think it would ever make sense to try to delta gzip'd or bzip'd contents.
>
> I also don't use "`binary`", as I use a custom diff driver instead (binary
>   implies "`-diff`").
>
> As for what should be the default, until now the default has always been that no gitattributes are defined by default. This is nice because it's simple to understand; **git doesn't care about filenames unless you tell it to**.
>   The downside obviously is that it may not perform optimally for some unusual workloads without extra configuration.

The [`.gitattributes` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html) mentions:

> The simplest way to mark a file as binary is to unset the diff attribute in the .gitattributes file:

```
*.ps -diff
```

> This will cause Git to generate Binary files differ (or a binary patch, if binary patches are enabled) instead of a regular diff.

So, yes "Setting the "`binary`" attribute also unsets the "`text`" and "`diff`" attributes as above", but Jeff was saying it was using only `-diff` in his case, which was enough to lark the file as binary.

Comment: So what about *.jpg binary -delta implies that this is setting delta to false. It's not as if it says "delta=false" or similar. EDIT: I'm being dumb. in the docs that flag is precisely what sets it to do what you said it does.

Comment: @IamPolaris yes, the `-delta` is the syntax used in a `.gitattributes` file to set it to 'false'

Comment: And `binary` is a shortcut for `-diff` ?

Comment: From the docs:
`Setting the "binary" attribute also unsets the "text" and "diff" attributes as above.`