# Can git do linear commit deltas during garbage collecton?

Tags: git

Can git generate a linear delta history during garbage collection?

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077311/can-git-use-patch-diff-based-storage) I learned that, during garbage collection, git repacks and stores deltas instead of the full revisions it had before gc. I used this to my advantage to store a mysqldump as a backup and for free I get history and data compression.

My problem now is, now that there's a lot of history (once a day, for a few months), every time it does `git gc` git will rewrite the entire delta history (changing all data on the file system), and that makes offsite syncs transfer all that data. I wish my rsyncs would just have to transfer the new deltas.

Put another way, is there a way to get git to only repack what hasn't already been packed?

Comment: You could use git to transfer the files instead of rsync - it's designed to do *exactly this* after all.

Comment: Hm that's a solution but I hate to add additional steps beyond rsync to transfer backups. I just wish it could all work. Maybe I should just use another rcs.

Answer (score 0):

The requested functionality:

> ... is there a way to get git to only repack what hasn't already been packed?

Exactly matches what `git repack` does. From [the git-repack reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack):

> This command is used to combine all objects that do not currently reside in a "pack", into a pack.

Run without any options it will pack any loose (unpacked) objects but leave them on disk. This can be changed with the `-d` option:

> After packing, if the newly created packs make some existing packs redundant, remove the redundant packs. **Also run git prune-packed to remove redundant loose object files.**

Alternatively `git prune-packed` can be run manually.