# Best practice to have documentation and other project related files in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, repository, branch

I have an asp.net mvc project on Git. We also have lots of other files e.g. documentation in *.pdf, database scripts in the *.sql and models in the form of images (*.png, *.jpg). We also want to have this in Git, but the question is where?

Create new folders in the project e.g. docs, db-scripts, etc and commit that with the project?

Create a new branch with the documentation and the db-script?

Create a new git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question isn't specific to Git but applies to any version control system.

In general, it's a good idea to keep all of your project's assets (e.g. source code, documentation, scripts, binaries) in the *same* directory structure, where the different assets would be organized in subdirectories. That way when someone fetches the project from source control, they'd get *everything* that's related to that project without having to hunt down different pieces in other repositories.

When it comes to Git specifically, one consideration to make is whether your project has a lot of *large* binaries files (e.g. audio, video, raw images). Git's [storage mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/26396) is, in fact, notoriously [inefficient at handling big binaries that change often](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/05/handle-big-repositories-git/):

> By default Git will compress and store all
>   subsequent full versions of the binary assets, which is obviously not
>   optimal if you have many.

If you need to store *large binaries* in your Git repository, you should consider looking at a Git extension called [Git Large File Storage (LFS)](https://git-lfs.github.com/). Once this extension is installed, Git will store large binaries in a remote repository but still make it look like they're part of the local repository.

Answer (score 0):

While it is irrelevant how you store your documentation (except separate repository, unless a submodule) - you definitely don't want to use text file formats that cannot produce a diff that makes sence.

I'd just keep documentation close to the code itself, definitely not on a separate branch, since doc changes should reflect code changes and versioning is important in both.

Comment: Don't really understand what you recommend. Definitely not a new branch. Perhaps a new repo but I can have them in a separate folder together with the project?