# Git: get blob path in .git directory

Tags: git, git-plumbing

I want to access some blobs at some point in repo history.

Currently, I do that with `git show $REV:$PATH`. But files are quite large and I don't want them to be read and piped in script. I want to get their path and then read as plain files.

May I rely on layout described in current documentation (e.g. `.git/objects/ee/2403ffd236587a2b17ddc35b0e711fc99ba6a0`), get file hash and transform it into path manually? I mean that it will not change soon in future versions and objects directory always has this structure.
Is there simpler way to do that with some plumbing command?

Comment: What about [packed repositories](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack) (for examples, after executing `git repack -ad`)? In a packed repository blobs may not exist as standalone files.

Comment: The files in .git/objects are not the original data. They are compressed and have a small header. You gain nothing by accessing the files directly.

Comment: @Leon @j6t So, in other words, what I want is just a dream and direct accessing `.git` directory is still bad idea? I thought blobs always remain untouched...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the blob data *is* [inviolable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inviolable) and [sacrosanct](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sacrosanct), it's also in a format unusable to mere mortals:

- As [j6t said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908375/git-get-blob-path-in-git-directory#comment69030849_40908375), it's zlib-deflated (but this is an implementation detail, not a promise, i.e., you are not supposed to just open and read it and use a zlib inflator to restore it, you are supposed to let Git do that for you).
- As [Leon said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908375/git-get-blob-path-in-git-directory#comment69030178_40908375), it may have been *packed*, in which case there is no unpacked object file to open and read in the first place.  Instead, you would have to open the pack index files (to find the correct pack file) and then the correct pack file (to find the packing data with the directory that locates the object and its bases), and then undo the [xdelta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta) style, but [not actually xdelta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/1256452), compression of those items.

If you want to read the file with plumbing commands, you could first find the hash:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD~20:Makefile
bdb55792f11a9f9565c4aad147a492caed7f09c3
```

and then use `git cat-file -p` to extract the raw object, or `git cat-file -t` to get its type (or `--batch-check` to read information about the object, etc.).  Note that you can in fact just pass the path directly to `git cat-file` itself as well:

```
$ git cat-file -t HEAD~20:Makefile
blob
```

Note, however, one more potential stumbling block: when accessing the contents of a blob with either `git cat-file -p <blob-specifier>` or `git show <blob-specifier>`, you get the *in-repository format* of the data.  That is, when checking out a specific commit (with `git checkout`), Git will extract a `.gitattributes` file and/or use the `git config` settings to find smudge filters and/or CR-LF adjustments that are to be made.  These filters are applied to the in-repository data to produce the working-tree copy of the file.  But when you use `git show` or `git cat-file -p` to access the repository data, *no filters are used*.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer. Yes, I know that it's possible to do that with plumbing commands but the point was to get file itself... I understood now that this idea could not be implemented and will use output of `git show`. Also, good point that you explicitly noted that git doesn't touch new line symbols.

Comment: really good answer, also the note on that its inrepository format -> This is the case when you use LFS, I think you get the LFS Pointer file... if that is correct...

Comment: @Gabriel: yes, if you're using Git-LFS, what Git is storing is the LFS data that the (separate) LFS code uses to retrieve the file later.