# What types of binary files does Git keep deltas for?

Tags: git, git-lfs

We're dealing with a very large project that needs to be migrated to Git. Unfortunately, it contains a large number of binaries as well, some of which are zip-s, dll-s and so on. At the moment, it's not possible to remove these binaries from the version control system.

I would like to find out more about how Git keeps deltas for binary files and if, and for which ones it doesn't. I know this is configurable via the `.gitattributes` file, but do the file types need to be listed explicitly, or is there a pre-defined default set that it recognizes and handles automatically...?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, let's get a bit of terminology out of the way.  Files are stored as *blob objects*.  These are one of four object types, the other three being *commit*, *tree*, and *annotated tag*.

Git's model is that *all* objects are logically independent.  Everything is stored by its hash ID key, in a database.  To retrieve any object, you start by knowing its hash ID, which you get from something or someone else.<sup>1</sup>  You feed that hash ID to an object-getter, and it either looks up the object where it is stored directly, with no chance at delta compression at all—this is what Git calls a *loose object*—or, failing that, Git looks inside *pack files*, which pack multiple separate objects together and provide the opportunity for delta compression.<sup>2</sup>

What you're looking for, then, is information about which blob objects Git chooses to delta-compress against which other blob objects inside these pack files.  The answer has evolved somewhat over time, so there is no single correct answer—but there are certain control knobs, including the `.gitattributes` one you mentioned.

The actual delta format is a [modification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9478023/1256452) of [xdelta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta).  It can, literally, compress (or "deltify") any binary data against any other binary data—but the results will be poor unless the inputs are well-chosen.  It's the input choices that are the real key here.  Git also has a [technical documentation file describing how objects are chosen for deltification](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-heuristics.txt).  This takes file path names, and especially final path component names, into account.

Note that if deltification fails to make the object smaller, the object is simply not delta-compressed.  The object's original file size is *also* an input here, and `core.bigFileThreshold` (introduced in Git 1.7.6) sets a size value: files above this level are never deltified at all.

Hence, you can prevent Git from considering a file (object, really) for deltification by either of two ways:

- set `core.bigFileThreshold` so that the object is too big, or
- make the object's path name match a `.gitattributes` line that has `-delta` specified.

Note that when using Git-LFS, large files are not stored in Git at all.  Instead, a large file (as defined by the Git-LFS settings) is replaced (at `git add` time) by an indirect name.  Git then stores this indirect name as the blob object (using the original file's path).  When Git extracts the object, Git-LFS inspects it before allowing it to go into your work-tree.  Git-LFS detects that the object's data were replaced with an indirect name, and retrieves the "real" data from another (separate, not-Git-at-all) server using the indirect name.  So Git never sees the large file's data at all: instead, it sees only these indirect names.

---

<sup>1</sup>For instance, we might start with a branch name like `master`, which gets us the latest (or *tip*) commit hash ID.  That hash ID gives us access to the commit object.  The commit lists the hash ID of a tree.  The tree, once we obtain it, lists the hash ID of some blob, along with the file's name.  So, now we know that the hash ID for the version of `README` in the tip commit of `master`, if that's what we're looking for.  Or, we use the commit data to find an older commit, which we use to find another even-older commit, and so on, until we arrive at the commit we want; and *then* we use the tree to find the blob IDs (and names) of files.

<sup>2</sup>Normally, an object can only be "deltified" against other objects in the same pack.  For transport purposes, Git provides what it calls a *thin pack* in which objects can be delta-compressed against other objects that are omitted, but are assumed to be available on the other side of the transport mechanism.  The other Git must "fatten up" the thin pack.

Answer (score 2):

> Hence, you can prevent Git from considering a file (object, really) for deltification by either of two ways:
>
> - set core.bigFileThreshold so that the object is too big, or
> - make the object's path name match a .gitattributes line that has -delta specified.

That part from [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48305739/6309) is now clearly documented with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021):

See [commit 3a837b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a837b58e33ee67f21a2ca737c6a12d74cee9e5e) (21 Feb 2021) by [Christian Walther (`cwalther`)](https://github.com/cwalther).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ccf6861](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccf6861b7272f99ab078345e1ee6d6b37b742cc0), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a837b58e33ee67f21a2ca737c6a12d74cee9e5e): mention bigFileThreshold for packing
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Walther</sup>

> Knowing about the `core.bigFileThreshold` configuration variable is helpful when examining pack file size differences between repositories.
> Add a reference to it to the manpages a user is likely to read in this situation.

`git pack-objects` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a837b58e33ee67f21a2ca737c6a12d74cee9e5e/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt#L403-L413):

> ### CONFIGURATION
>
> Various configuration variables affect packing, see
> [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) (search for "pack" and "delta").
>
> Notably, delta compression is not used on objects larger than the
> `core.bigFileThreshold` configuration variable and on files with the
> attribute `delta` set to false.

`git repack` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3a837b58e33ee67f21a2ca737c6a12d74cee9e5e/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L184-L187):

> Delta compression is not used on objects larger than the
> `core.bigFileThreshold` configuration variable and on files with the
> attribute `delta` set to false.

Answer (score 1):

git will hapilly store every file you feed it in the repository, be it binary or not, of any size. It will magically know how to compress the deltas, also for binary files (and I don't think you can control that). This is even true if you're not using git-lfs. It is not a recommended practice, because it makes your repository large. Since a git working copy always contains the whole history, it will stay large forever. If you use git-lfs, at least you will only have the latest versions of the large files in your working copy (for the downside that you need a connection to the server for many more operations, as with subversion).

Would it be an option to split the binaries into their own repository and embed it as module?

Comment: Based on some articles that I've come across, it appears that you could control the deltas per file type using the `.gitattributes` file and defining `*.zip binary -delta` in it, for example. I was wondering for which file types this is actually necessary, as I guess Git would know that you can't really compress a zip file much (if of course it's already compressed)

Comment: @carlspring; According to https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes "packing attributes", this will disable delta compression for zip files. Whether that reduces the repository size will probably highly depend on the nature of your zip files (and how often they change in the existing repo). You should try it out.