# Using Keys with JGit to Access a Git Repository Securely

Tags: java, git, ssh, jsch, jgit

I'm using [JGit](http://www.jgit.org/) to access a remote Git repo, and I need to use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) for it. JGit uses [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to provide secure access. However, I'm not sure how to set the key file and the knows hosts file for JGit. What I have tried is as follows.

Created a custom configuration of the [SshSessionFactory](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/SshSessionFactory.html), using by subclassing [JSchConfigSessionFactory](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/JschConfigSessionFactory.html):

```
public class CustomJschConfigSessionFactory extends JschConfigSessionFactory {
    @Override
    protected void configure(OpenSshConfig.Host host, Session session) {
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");
    }
}
```

In the class which I access the remote Git repo, did the following:

```
CustomJschConfigSessionFactory jschConfigSessionFactory = new CustomJschConfigSessionFactory();

JSch jsch = new JSch();
try {
    jsch.addIdentity(".ssh/id_rsa");
    jsch.setKnownHosts(".ssh/known_hosts");
} catch (JSchException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
    SshSessionFactory.setInstance(jschConfigSessionFactory);
```

I can't figure out how to associate this JSch object with JGit so that it can successfully connect to the remote repository. When I try to clone it with JGit, I get the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@git.test.com:abc.org/test_repo.git: reject HostKey: git.test.com
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
at GitTest.cloneRepo(GitTest.java:109)
at GitTest.main(GitTest.java:223)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@git.test.com:abc.org/test_repo.git: reject HostKey: git.test.com
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1104)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)
... 9 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: git.test.com
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:748)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:321)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
... 16 more
```

I have added the git.test.com entry to my `/etc/hosts` file. I have used the same code to access a git repo with a http url, so the code it working fine. It's the key handling part that is failing. Any idea on how to handle this?

Comment: I see that you created a jsch object, but you haven't assigned it to anything. Why have you created it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to find the issue. The public key in the server side had a different name other than the usual id_rsa.pub, while the private key on my side was id_rsa. JSch expects by default the public key to have the same name as the private key plus the .pub suffix. Using a key pair with a common name (ex.: private = key_1 and public = key_1.pub) solves the issue.

Answer (score 14):

You need to override the `getJSch` method in your custom factory class:

```
class CustomConfigSessionFactory extends JschConfigSessionFactory
{
    @Override
    protected JSch getJSch(final OpenSshConfig.Host hc, FS fs) throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = super.getJSch(hc, fs);
        jsch.removeAllIdentity();
        jsch.addIdentity( "/path/to/private/key" );
        return jsch;
    }
}
```

Calling `jsch.removeAllIdentity` is important; it doesn't seem to work without it.

A caveat: I wrote the above in Scala, and then translated it over to Java, so it might not be quite right. The original Scala is as follows:

```
class CustomConfigSessionFactory extends JschConfigSessionFactory
{
    override protected def getJSch( hc : OpenSshConfig.Host, fs : FS ) : JSch =
    {
        val jsch = super.getJSch(hc, fs)
        jsch.removeAllIdentity()
        jsch.addIdentity( "/path/to/private/key" )
        jsch
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem was that I needed to be able to specify the passphrase for the private key, which you can either add as another parameter to `addIdentity` or by creating your own class that implements `UserInfo` and then set the `session` parameter to the `configure` method of `CustomConfigSessionFactory` to use that `UserInfo`.

Comment: Special thanks for the `jsch.removeAllIdentity()` hint!

Comment: What I'm seeing is that still the ~/.ssh/id_rsa is returned from the Host but found no way to set this to null so it returns the one set in the code.

Answer (score 6):

Jsch sesems to not like a known_hosts file in the hashed format-- it must conform to the format produced by:

`ssh-keyscan -t rsa hostname >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

e.g.

```
<hostname> ssh-rsa <longstring/longstring>
```

not:

```
 |1|<hashed hostname>= ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 <hashed fingerprint>=
```