# Specifying SSH key for JGit

Tags: java, git, ssh, jsch, jgit

I'm wondering how I can use jgit to connect to github using a specified ssh key file (i.e. one not in `~/.ssh/`).

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to use `JschConfigSessionFactory` properly. I've tried creating a setup just like the one in this article: [Using Keys with JGit to Access a Git Repository Securely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686643/using-keys-with-jgit-to-access-a-git-repository-securely)

I call git using `git.push().setRemote(remotePath).call();` However, I get this error (specific repository omitted from log):

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/user/repo: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:160)
    at gitio.GitInterface.pushToRemote(GitInterface.java:145)
    at engine.GitInterfaceTester.main(GitInterfaceTester.java:25)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/user/repo: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openPush(TransportHttp.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java:156)
    ... 2 more
```

I've noticed that the custom overriden methods in `JschConfigSessionFactory` aren't ever actually invoked. This is almost certainly the cause of the problem... but don't know why they're not invoked; I pass the custom `JschConfigSessionFactory` to `SshSessionFactory` using `SshSessionFactory.setInstance(sessionFactory);`

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this example help? https://gist.github.com/quidryan/5449155

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GitHub uses password authentication for https URLs and public-key authentication for SSH URLs (see https://gist.github.com/grawity/4392747).

The `SshSessionFactory` is only consulted for SSH URLs like git@github.com:user/repo.git. To authenticate for an https URL you can use the `CredentialsProvider`. The base class for commands that may establish connections is `TransportCommand` and has a `setCredentialsProvider()` method.
If you equip the `PushCommand` with a `CredentialsProvider` that supplies user name and password, you should be able to successfully establish a connection.

For further details about authenticating with JGit you may want to read this article: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/

Comment: Ahh, I see; I used the wrong URL style. git@github.com:user/repo.git worked. Thank you!