# How to login to github in Java?

Tags: java, github, jgit

I want to create a Java program which will login to a github account using username and password. I am using JGit library. I can see example snippets for git commands(commit,pull, etc) but not for login.

I know that JGit provides CredentialsProvider and UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider for username and password, but I do not know how to use it to login to an account.

Comment: Perhaps you should try the documentation.

Comment: I have also gone through the documentation. JGit has HttpAuthMethod class but it is protected and therefore, not accessible.

Comment: [Here is another example you might find useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545311/jgit-clone-repository).

Answer (score 0):

This blog will help to get an understanding on the use of UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider, http://gautirao.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/toying-around-with-jgit/

Comment: Linking a blog is hardly a good answer, imo. Please, at least include some code and/or write a short explanation.

Comment: Posting some code is necessary as blog posts and even whole sites can vanish in time but SO is about keeping the valuable answer for future use/search.

Comment: I am looking for code which can authenticate username and password.